# How to find $\int_{0}^{4} \sqrt{16-x^2} dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What is the easiest way of solving this integral:

$$\int_{0}^{4} \sqrt{16-x^2} dx$$

My idea was to substitute $x$ with $4\sin u$ and to get under the square root $\cos^{2}{u}$ so i can get rid of it, but then i get again $\cos^{2}u$. I suppose that could be solved using formula

$$\cos^{2}{\frac{u}{2}} = \frac{1+\cos u}{2}$$

But then I got troubles with getting back substitution.

Am I making somewhere mistake and if not how should I precede, or is there some easier way of solving it?

Comment: If you want the easiest way (without substitution) then you can interpret the integral as the quarter area under the circle $x^2+y^2=16$, so the answer will be $1/4(\pi)(4^2)$.

Comment: General tip: when you do a substitution for a definite integral, you can change the limits of integration and then not have to substitute backwards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this integral is to notice that the curve $y=\sqrt{16-x^2}$ is one quarter of a circle, so the area under this curve will be one quarter the area of the circle. The circle has radius $4$, so area $\pi 4^2 = 16\pi$.

This means the integral must evaluate to $4\pi$.

Comment: It seems like very simple answer but i have trouble with figuring out how is $ y = \sqrt{16-x^{2}}$ one quarter of circle.

Comment: @ZvnokyBrown If $y=\sqrt{16-x^2}$, then $y^2=16-x^2$ and $x^2+y^2=4^2$...

Comment: and $y$ is always non-negative,...

Comment: How do you rigorously get the area of a circle though? I am a little afraid this reasoning might be a little... circular.

Answer (score 13):

With the suggested substitution,

$$\int_0^4\sqrt{16-x^2}dx=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}16\cos^2u\,du=8\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos2u+1)\,du.$$

As $\cos2u$ runs from $1$ to $-1$ symmetrically, this contribution vanishes and $4\pi$ remain.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think you lost your square root around $16\cos^2(u)$

Comment: Nevermind, I definitely forgot the dx => du portion.

Answer (score 2):

Does the answer have to be algebraically derived? If not, just draw it, recognize that it's a quarter of a circle with radius 4, thus the answer is $$\frac{\pi 4^2}{4} = 4\pi.$$

If you require something more analytic, you can work backward through double integrals:
$$
\int_0^4 \sqrt{16-\cos^2 x} \operatorname{d} x  = \int_0^4 \int_0^{\sqrt{16-\cos^2 x}} 1 \operatorname{d} y \operatorname{d} x.$$
From there, you again draw the integration region, and do a change of variables to polar coordinates:
$$\begin{align}
x &= r\cos\theta \\
y &= r\sin\theta \Rightarrow \\
I &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^4 r \operatorname{d} r \operatorname{d} \theta \\
 & = \frac{\pi}{2} \left(\frac{4^2}{2}\right) = 4\pi
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

First notice that $$\int_0^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}dx=r^2\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx.$$

Then by parts,

$$I=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\left.x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right|_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.$$

But $x^2=1-(1-x^2)$ so that

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx-I.$$
The remaining integral is solved with an arc sine and yields $\pi/2$.

Comment: Notes:
1) u-substitution: let $x=r u \rightarrow dx = r du$